# How to draw diagonal table borders in latex, like in Excel?

Tags: excel, latex

Is it possible to draw diagonal (parallelogram) cells in LaTeX: the cell content is diagonal, and the cell's originally vertical borders are also diagonal.

Here is what I managed to do using the rotating package:

```
\begin{tabular}{|r|c|c|}
\hline
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
 & \begin{rotate}{45}Trying to save some horizontal space\end{rotate} & \begin{rotate}{45}While keeping headers readable\end{rotate} \\
\hline
this & is & a \\
\hline
sample & latex & table \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Here is a screenshot of the output vs what is possible using Excel:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solution is to insert a picture created by another program (in this case Excel).

Comment: Inserting pictures is much more reasonable for graphics than for something like this. With a table, there are at least two significant issues: formatting won't match, and you can't use math mode.

Comment: I suspect that PGF-TiKZ can probably do what you want, but it's beyond my abilities to give you any help with that.

Comment: This should be definitely moved to [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Removed my comment. I see it also. Must be a temp glitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: LaTeX regular tables don't have that capability.

Long answer: It can surely be done but with more effort, as shown by similar (but not quite the same) questions in [Tex.Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/):

- [Inclined line between two cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20760/10944)
- [Diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17745/10944)